# TypeScript does not expand generic and complains about type arguments being not comparable

Tags: typescript, generics, structural-typing

I'm working with a data structure that exists in two variants: a complete version for the output and an incomplete version where some properties are nullable during intermediate processing. Most functions expect the complete version of the type, some can work with both. Since it's a complex tree-like data structure with a lot of discriminated unions, instead of defining the type for the incomplete variant as a union, I wanted to use a generic parameter, the basic idea being

```
interface Data<Mode = 'DONE'>  {
    someProperty: Mode extends 'BUILD' ? string | null : string;
}

type FullData = Data<'DONE'>; // or just `Data`, using the default
type TempData = Data<'BUILD'>;
```

Now some functions will want to check whether the data is actually complete, and can then call another function that expects the complete data:

```
function example(doneVal: Data<'DONE'>) {}

function caller(buildVal: Data<'BUILD'>) {
  if (buildVal.someProperty != null) {
    example(buildVal);
  }
}
```

However, [this produces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgJYDs4hgMwIYGMQIAi2c2APALJQAmB46K1AzggOQBCAqgJIAyhrBAB82hAPIA5AKKsAfAgQBvYAEgmUALYgACjCgQMcAJ4AuBFVoJ6IRiw49+ggPwImcGKgDmwhCgCuADYBCGZuHiieANzAAL7AwJh+KLhwSFAoVmDYGhABIAAU1OkgAGrYAWbEpGSs4tJyAJRKcQlJKWkZuOV5MPkARn5IAdRlFUQk5PZ8ArJNygpImAj9g8OjAHTqWrr6hkYIAIQAvL6BAXPACgrg2bkFA0Mj5Q3RCnExQA) the error message

> `Argument of type 'Data<"BUILD">' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Data<"DONE">'.`
>  `Type '"BUILD"' is not assignable to type '"DONE"'.` (ts2345)

Ok, I get it, TypeScript cannot infer from the `someProperty != null` check that `buildVal` is of the correct type, but even when I use a type assertion

```
example(buildVal as Data<'DONE'>);
```

it [still complains](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=39&pln=10&pc=39#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgJYDs4hgMwIYGMQIAi2c2APALJQAmB46K1AzggOQBCAqgJIAyhrBAB82hAPIA5AKKsAfAgQBvYAEgmUALYgACjCgQMcAJ4AuBFVoJ6IRiw49+ggPwImcGKgDmwhCgCuADYBCGZuHiieANzAAL7AwJh+KLhwSFAoVmDYGhABIAAU1OkgAGrYAWbEpGSs4tJyAJRKcQlJKWkZuOV5MPkARn5IAdRlFUQk5PZ8ArJNygpImAj9g8OjAHTqWrr6hkYIAIQAvL6BAXPACgrg2bkFA0Mj5QjYLFWTdTKz0QpxMUA)

> `Conversion of type 'Data<"BUILD">' to type 'Data<"DONE">' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other.`
>  `Type '"BUILD"' is not comparable to type '"DONE"'`

What gives? It seems TypeScript is not actually comparing the types structurally, but rather by name?!

If I were to [spell out the types in both variants](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=25&pln=12&pc=33#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgGwQEQIbFVAvFA3gKAEgBnAewFsIAFAJ1MhtAC4pjgaBLAOwHMBufAF98oSFAAqEcmDQZseImUq16ERiBZtOvKAB8oXRAgGCB+AGZwuAY2AdSXKBAAeqaQggAKACYOIANVQEFngkWVQASjxhCytbe0drII8aTwAjOA4Eb0DgiSkZdEiFKCgOcyh0zOzcgDolajoGUCgAQhxDJCiCUtKXNzAPKqycoKhUYlgjcIiBUuFBIA) instead of using a single generic type, it works just fine.

I can work around this by [using a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgJYDs4hgMwIYGMQIAi2c2APALJQAmB46K1AzggOQBCAqgJIAyhrBAB82hAPIA5AKKsAfAgQBvYAEgmUALYgACjCgQMcAJ4AuBFVoJ6IRiw49+ggPwImcGKgDmwhCgCuADYBCGZuHiieANzAAL7AwJh+KLhwSFAoVmDYGhABIAAU1OkgAGrYAWbEpGSs4tJyAJRKcQlJKWkZuOV5MPkARn5IAdRlFUQk5PZ8ArJNygpImAj5SEyExf2Dw6MNc8AKCuDZuQUDQyPlDdEKcS2JyanpyGsbTJUTNVzTcj5Vk3UyWahZ7jaq1SSApT7BAwEBwPwwDJMAB06i0un0hiMCAAhABeXyBALRGJAA) (which also means I don't have to explicitly assert the type in the call), but I'd still like to understand what is happening. So far, my experimentation shows that the error message changes when I use `'BUILD' extends Mode` instead of `Mode extends 'BUILD'` in the type condition (I never know which one to use), and that the default parameter type does not matter (`Data<Mode>` or `Data<Mode extends 'DONE' | 'BUILD'>`).

*Edit*: after some further experimentation, I found that using `type TempData = Data<'BUILD'> | Data<'DONE'>` or `Data<'BUILD' | 'DONE'>` lets me do the cast, but I don't like the verbosity of that. And I'd still like to understand why my original attempt doesn't work :-)

Comment: TS takes a shortcut comparing two instantiations of the same generic type (if the generic type has variance markers, which happens implicitly unless you add your own with `in` `out` etc). So when comparing `Data<X>` to `Data<Y>` the checker compares `X` to `Y`. Then it bails out because `X` and `Y` are not comparable to each other. So yes, sometimes it compares types by "name" (declaration), since full structural comparison would be prohibitively expensive if done everywhere. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an explanation with sources; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz OMG that seems to be the answer. Where the hell is that documented? (And how did you learn about this?) Would this be considered a bug in TS, that it should not use this shortcut unless it can actually prove that the type parameter is actually used structurally in the resulting type?

Comment: @jcalz Also can you recommend a good read about the implications of using `'BUILD' extends Mode` vs `Mode extends 'BUILD'` for the type condition?

Comment: I will point to github issues discussing the variance markers when I write up my answer.  It's possible that there is a bug where the variance marker on `Data<T>` is incorrect, but I'm not sure and I'll have to look at it more.  I don't know what to say about `'BUILD' extends Mode` vs the reverse, at least not as it relates to the question about variance markers; it's presumably a followup or extra question?

Comment: I'm happy to ask a followup question, yes, I thought maybe you'd remember a canonical duplicate

Comment: I think this may be the same bug as [ms/TS#44945](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44945), and the fix for it has been postponed for a long time.  I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Also what is the heuristic to use the structural vs by-name comparison? I would have expected that [the approach from sheeldotme's answer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBA6gSxACwLIHsAmUA8AVAGhlRgF4YByAEQHkA5AUQoD4yYBvAbQGsowYEAOxi8w6AGYw8AXQBcxGFAAeIKIMwBnSrUYUYAfik8+0mPKOjTAHxiCArgBsHAX2DAhqgE7iAhgGNYKh8QHxgOYABIDXQAWygABU90aE9weQ0QTyEAcwBuYFdQSFgAMUcHIJC2RBQMbBxKnyJqeiZmfPBoKSgYiEbqpDQsXEbmgCEAVQBJABkqFnzgcTtBPxAEdGFlH16HKAAKTE2oADUfB3kyp0aASg5C5dX1zZg-c73PfYAjOwQHTDOF26vVu4TCCEk31+-0BADponFEskoKl+ABCcj2Jx3djAMJhba7A4-P4A84wHxaK4VYI+G75MKuZxAA) would fail as well.

Comment: I don't think I can expand the scope of an answer to all-things-variance-marker, unfortunately.  Presumably something about the form of the type causes the compiler to decide that the variance is unreliable or unmeasurable, in which case it will fall back to a structural comparison.  But the specifics about how the compiler chooses to make such decisions are not known to me, change occasionally, and are probably out of scope for the original question as asked.  Is it okay if I focus on the question as asked from here on out?

Comment: Sure. Write the answer and you'll get an upvote either way :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At its core TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), where two types are considered compatible based on their *shapes* or *structures*. This is in opposition to [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), where types are considered compatible based on their *names* or *declarations*.

So while a nominally typed language can quickly and easily decide if two types are the compatible by just looking at their declarations, a structurally typed language might have to do a lot of work to make a decision.  A nominal language can say "oh, `A` and `B` are obviously different because they came from different places", while a structural language has to break `A` and `B` apart into their members, and into the members of their members, and so on, until it finds some differing structure.  We can call that a *full structural comparison* of two types, and while it is sometimes necessary to do that, TypeScript would be almost unusable if that were the *only* way to compare types.

Luckily, it's not.  There are shortcuts, some of which involve nominal types.  Yes, **sometimes TypeScript performs nominal type checks.**

---

One obvious shortcut (that you might not even consider a shortcut) is to say that `A` is identical to `A`.  You don't have to do a full structural comparison on them, because they are nominally identical.  They're the same type before you even look at structure.  So nominal equivalence implies structural equivalence.

Another shortcut involves [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types.  **If you are comparing `F<X>` to `F<Y>` for the same `F`, then you *might* be able to just compare `X` to `Y` to get the same result.**  This depends on the generic type `F<T>` having a known *variance*. (See [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) for more information about variance.)

TypeScript lets you manually assign **variance markers** to generic types via [`in` and `out` annotations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#optional-variance-annotations-for-type-parameters), but even if you don't do that, the compiler will infer such markers internally, depending on the ways the type parameter appears in the structure.  (Manually assigned variance markers are just a convenience for performance, relieving the compiler from having to infer them.)

So, if `F<T>` is known to be *covariant* in `T`, then `F<X> extends F<Y>` if and only if `X extends Y`.  So there's no point in fully instantiating `F<X>` and `F<Y>` and comparing them structurally.  The compiler can just reduce the problem to comparing `X` and `Y`.  Similar things can be said if `F<T>` is known to be *contravariant*, or *bivariant*, or *invariant*.  These speed up type checking for generics immensely.

Of course sometimes the structure of a generic type is complicated in such a way that the compiler cannot be sure about the variance marker, and either decides that it is *unreliable* (meaning it will do a followup structural check but only if the comparison fails) or *unmeasurable* (meaning it will always do a structural check).

If the compiler always assigned accurate variance markers, then you would rarely notice the difference between a structural check and a nominal check (other than compiler performance), because they'd always give the same results.

Unfortunately this is not the case.

---

The problem is that **sometimes the compiler assigns an inaccurate variance marker to a generic type**.  There are several open issues in GitHub where this is the underlying problem.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#31251](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31251) and [microsoft/TypeScript#44945](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44945).  Apparently, the compiler often misassigns variance markers when the type parameter appears inside [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), such as `Mode extends 'BUILD' ? string | null : string` inside `type Data<Mode ⋯> = ⋯`.

And so in your code, the compiler ends up comparing `Data<"BUILD">` and `Data<"DONE">` by just comparing `"BUILD"` and `"DONE"`.  These literal types are unrelated to each other, so the compiler concludes that `Data<"BUILD">` and `Data<"DONE">` are also unrelated to each other.

Oops.

---

Presumably if microsoft/TypeScript#44945 is ever fixed, your code would start working as written.

While it would theoretically always be correct to fix it by just marking things as unmeasurable, doing so isn't always feasible.  It tends to make performance worse, as mentioned above.  Also, it tends to *destabilize* a lot of existing code, so even if it does things "correctly", it could do so in a way that has a lot of far-reaching changes that need to be addressed.  (For example, it could change the order of operations somewhere and now the compiler sees a circularity issue where there wasn't one before).  There was a proposed fix for the issue here at [microsoft/TypeScript#43387](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43887) which would mark all generic conditional types as unmeasurable, but it was never merged, apparently because of unexpected breakages elsewhere.

Oh well. Maybe some other more suitable fix will happen someday.